# How to get child object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to access **FirstPersonCharacter** from my script by using FPSController.

[image]

I pass **FPSController** to my script. Now I try to intialize **FirstPersonCharacter** which is a child of FPSController.

I pass FPSController to the script, now I try to use FPSController to initialize FirstPersonCharacter, because I try to avoid too many public variables, especially if it is not necessary.

```
public GameObject FPSController;
private GameObject FirstPersonCharacter;
```

I need help at the initialisation part:

```
void Start()
{
    FirstPersonCharacter = ???
}
```

I tried it like this:

```
void Start()
{
    FirstPersonCharacter = FPSController.transform.GetChild(0);
}
```

But I get `Cannot implicitly convert type "UnityEngine.Transform" to "UnityEngine.GameObject"`

Answer (score 0):

It works like this:

```
FirstPersonCharacter = FPSController.transform.GetChild(0).transform.gameObject;
```

Comment: You just need FPSController.transform.GetChild(0).gameObject;